# Android Spinner Filter ListView

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have code below. This is spinner with customadapter. Data from spinner are from SQLITE db. Without filtering spinner w item works OK. But currently the problem is that, spinner show only one item and list is not filter anyway. Any help? Thanks a lot.

```
        ArrayList<String> my_array = getTableValues();
        my_Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, my_array);
        spinner.setAdapter(my_Adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object object = my_Adapter.getItem(position);


                my_Adapter.getFilter().filter(object.toString(), new Filter.FilterListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after setting it. This makes associated views aware that the underlying data has changed and that a repaint is required.